# Как в Laravel транспилировать arrow function в es5?

Tags: laravel, babel, laravel-mix

Есть стрелочная функция javascript нужно транспилировать его в es5 знаю что для этого нужно использовать Babel, но в документации Laravel 5.7 об этом нету слова(в прежних версия была функция `mix.babel()`)

Как  в Laravel  транспилировать стрелочную функцию в es5 ?

Comment: эмммм.. есть же laravel mix

Comment: Мне интересует   что делать конкретно (пример или пошагово) в документации ничего об том не говорится  более того функция `mix.babel()`  в новой версии Laravel  отсутствует

Comment: как это не говоритсья написано же ясно __With this single line of code, you may now take advantage of:

ES2015 syntax.__

Comment: mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');